# Needing RDF sample dataset

Tags: dataset, faceted-search, facet, rdfstore, allegrograph

Hi everyone
Ive been looking for some time now for a big enough semantic dataset to do some testing on an algorithm Im developing.

With this I mean an already existing RDF/XML file that I could "easily" upload to AllegroGraph. I have found several dummy datasets but they use unrealistic data, as in "char1", "char2", "node121", etc. Which is ok at first.

But now I need to test using a dataset about real stuff, be it cars, plants, movies, books, etc. A combination of several would be ideal. Specifically one with over 50k object with at least 3 or 4 facets.
I have been told these datasets are somewhere out there but I cant find them.

Any links, pointers or suggestions are more tha welcome. Also if there is a better site to post this question i will follow the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after looking more time I ran into a very good option.
That is [DBpedia.org](http://DBpedia.org)
They collect all the data from Wikipedia and divide it into specific parts.
For my testing purposes I will most probably be using
I guess my problem was that I am still getting familiarized with the concepts and how to search for what i want when it comes to semantic web. Hopefully this link will help more people :)